# put H2 between Div jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
<h2></h2>
<h2></h2>
<h2></h2>
<h2></h2>
```

I want it to be like this using jQuery so if anyone can help please

```
<div class="dotted">
     <h2></h2>
</div>

<div class="dotted">
     <h2></h2>
</div>

<div class="dotted">
     <h2></h2>
</div>

<div class="dotted">
     <h2></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: jQuery website has a nice documentation : http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-around/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, use .wrap()

```
$('h2').wrap('<div class="dotted"></div>')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AvkY5/6/)

Comment: thanks for you answer totally works !